# Unable to declare FilePointer Array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, pointers

I am trying to compile C++ program in VS2010. I am using the below code but getting error while compiling.

```
int c=1;
FILE *f[c+2];
```

The error says that I cannot use `c` there. It has to be constant value, but my requirement is that I cannot use constant there. Please suggest.

Thanks,
Amit Agarwal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, an array whose size is not a constant expression is spelled `vector`:

```
int c=1;
vector<FILE*> f(c+2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use dynamic allocation:

```
int c=1;
FILE *f = new FILE[c+2];
```

But, be sure to free the pointers when you are finished using them:

```
delete []f;
```

Better yet, you could use `std::unique_ptr` VS 2010 supports it:

```
int c=1;
std::unique_ptr<FILE[]> fp(new FILE[c+2]);
```

Be sure to include `#include<memory>` where `std::unique_ptr` is declared.

The advantage is that you don't have to use `delete []` to free the pointer. Compiler takes care of the memory management.

Comment: Thanks Hariprasad for your help but none of the above worked for me. The first one gave me error :
error : no operator found which takes a right-hand operator of type FILE *(or there is no acceptable conversion)
Second solution didnt work either. :(

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I am working on VS2010. Not sure bout the compiler though. My code is working fine in other software where the compiler is gcc.

Answer (score 0):

VS doesn't comes with C99 compiler, and does not support variable length arrays.
So, the array dimension should be a constant.

```
int c=1;
FILE *f[3];
```

Since you need to allocate dynamically, Instead you can go with

```
int c=5;
FILE *f = new FILE[c+2];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this as below:

> #define  MAX_FILES
>
> FILE* f[MAX_FILES+1];

Or you go with dynamic allocation with 'new'

Comment: His requirements are that he needs MAX_FILES to be a runtime dynamic parameter, and not a compile time constant.

Comment: He didn't specified that.  So I provided this one and also mentioned about dynamic allocation as well.